# I want to find the name who got the second maximum salary from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle.

I want to find the name who got the second maximum salary from a table?

Here the example table:

```
R.no    name       employee_id     salary
201     Sanjay      78781          1000
202     Mohan       78782          2500 
203     Viji        78783          5000
204     Vinay       78784          3000
205     Ishanth     78785          8000
```

Comment: What if there are 2 names with value 5000.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (
   select name, 
          salary, 
          dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rnk
   from table_name
) t
where rnk = 2
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e93c3/1

Comment: @balamurugan: I fixed the order by. The `desc` was missing at first.

Comment: @balamurugan: it's an alias for the derived table (the inner select).